# How to change the python executable used by spark workers at runtime from within a Jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I'm setting up a Spark cluster using YARN with Jupyterhub running on the  master node. I've installed python 2 and 3 on all nodes using conda, and I want users to be able to specify which version of Python they execute code with. This is necessary as some libraries used in Python UDFs do not yet support Python 3.

I've created the kernel config file

```
{
    "argv": [
        "python",
        "-m",
        "ipykernel_launcher",
        "-f",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "display_name": "Python 3",
    "language": "python",
    "env": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python3",
        "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON": "/opt/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python"
    }
}
```

to point to the correct python executable, and created a session using

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession \
   .builder \
   .appName("MyApp") \
   .config("spark.pyspark.python", "/opt/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python")\
   .config("spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH", "/opt/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python")\
   .getOrCreate()
```

which also sets the python executable in two different ways. When looking at the Environment tab of the Spark UI, these values are correctly set.

However when I run any spark query (e.g. the calculating pi example) I get `Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.`

How can I specify the python executable from within a Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the environment variables in python from your notebook, prior to creating a spark session.

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/opt/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = '/opt/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python'

# ....
spark = SparkSession.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thanks! TIL setting the env variables in a Jupyter kernel configuration does not set them in a notebook running that kernel.